# setting pub-sub-domain using Java DSL

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to convert the following to spring-integration java dsl.

```
   <int:channel id="partsSubscriberChannel" />

   <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
      id="jmsPartsInbound"
      acknowledge="transacted"
      destination-name="parts.topic"
      channel="partsSubscriberChannel"
      pub-sub-domain="true"
      connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
```

This is what I am up to:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel partsErrorChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel partsSubscriberChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}     

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow partsSubscription(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                    .id("partsJmsSubscriber")
                    .destination(Topic.PARTS.getName())
                    .outputChannel(partsSubscriberChannel())
                    .errorChannel(partsErrorChannel()))
            .get();
}
```

How do I set the `pub-sub-domain` and `acknowledge` xml attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently available directly using the DSL, but you can wire in a listener container with the property set...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDriverFlowWithContainer() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(container())
                    .id("foo"))
                    .errorChannel(errorChannel()))
            .channel(outputChannel()
            .get();
}

@Bean
public AbstractMessageListenerContainer container() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setSessionTransacted(true);
    container.setDestinationName(Topic.PARTS.getName());
    container.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return container;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, does the AbstractMessageListenerContainer need to be a @Bean?  The reason is that I wll be creating many of these with different topics, so Topic.PARTS.getName() would be passed an argument.

Comment: No, it does not, as long as you don't need to get it as a reference later (such as to change the concurrent consumers etc, at runtime). By the way, I created a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/pull/41) earlier to add a factory method to `Jms` to build the container. But, it will be a little while before it's integrated into a release.

Comment: I am actually gettting `org.springframework.core.ConstantException: Field 'AUTO' not found in class [javax.jms.Session]` now.

Comment: Sorry - it's AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE - but you can omit that because it's the default.

Comment: that fixed that issue, I am however getting `org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application:8087.jmsMessageDriverFlowWithContainer.channel#0'`, I would have thought that the outputChannel would have sorted that.  Any ideas?

Comment: I should mentions also that I am attaching to the channel via `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = SubscriberChannel.PARTS)` where `SubscriberChannel.PARTS = "jmsMessageDriverFlowWithContainer"`

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `SubscriberChannel.PARTS =  "partsSubscriberChannel"`